# How can I hide a jquery div when others are toggled open

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I am creating a format to post things to a user's feed and there are three options, text, image, and link. They all have a div that uses jquery to pop down. I am unable to figure out how to hide the other divs when one is open, and another one is clicked. The jsfiddle shows it clearly.

Thanks in advance for anything you could recommend.

http://jsfiddle.net/NFTFw/252/

```
$('input[name=text]').click(function () {
   $('#textpost').slideToggle($(this).is(':checked'));
    });
$('input[name=link]').click(function () {
   $('#linkpost').slideToggle($(this).is(':checked'));
    });
$('input[name=image]').click(function () {
   $('#imagepost').slideToggle($(this).is(':checked'));
    });
```

Comment: What happens if somebody checks 2 checkboxes? both section should be open?

Comment: If someone checks more than one box than only the box they clicked should be open. Meaning the other one is hidden, or closed.

Comment: Then you should probably go for radio button instead of checkboxes.

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything. What should happen if more than one checkbox is checked? Should you be using radio buttons for this?

Comment: Incidentally, note the shared `id` of the checkboxes: an [`id` ***must*** be unique within the document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). Use a `class` instead (if they must share the same name/identifier.

Comment: Changed the ids to be unique and it works great. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding "radio" functionality to the checkboxes, and making it a little more dynamic, using the inputs name to select the element to slide.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
    $('#' + this.name + 'post').slideToggle(this.checked)
                               .siblings('div')
                               .slideUp();
    $(this).siblings('input').prop('checked', false);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NFTFw/260/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to implement both. New to jquery, really appreciate the answers.

Comment: Ids should be unique... Look at the check box ids they are all having the same. HTML is invalid too..

Comment: @PSL - Did'nt notice, as I did'nt use the ID, but yes, they should be unique in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code you could write a function that updates all three divs in order to display the correct one.

for example :

```
  function toggle(idList) {
  for(i=0;i<idList.length;i++){
  $(idList[i]).slideToggle($(this).is(':checked'));
}
 }
```

and

```
     var ids = [ 'name-link', 'name-image', 'name-text' ]; 
    $('input[name=text]').click(function () {
 toggle(ids);
});
  $('input[name=link]').click(function () {
 toggle(ids);
});
    $('input[name=image]').click(function () {
     toggle(ids);
});
```

This would work if you already have logic to make checkboxes behave like radio buttons.